# Continuous Ping with Timestamp to File

Tags: batch-file, text, timestamp, ping

I am wanting to run a continuous ping on an IP and write the results with timestamp to a text file.

I have tried the below code saved as a .bat file.   If I run it, it will ask me to input the IP address and then it makes the text file.   But it does nothing else.   If, I run it as admin, it will ping forever like it should, but it won't create or write to a text file.   I am using windows 10 pro.

```
@echo off

set /p host=host Address:
set logfile=Log_%host%.log

echo Target Host = %host% >%logfile%
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (echo %%A>>%logfile% && GOTO Ping)
:Ping
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A>>%logfile%
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A
    timeout 1 >NUL 
GOTO Ping)
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why it is behaving this way.

Comment: Did you check with `@Echo On` in an open cmd window? I would double quote the set commands and also the file names. Does the host name  being input qualify as valid file names?

Comment: add a `cd /d "%~dp0"` as second line (after `@echo off`). When you "run as administrator", your working folder is set to `%systemroot%\system32` (there you should find your logfiles so far)

Comment: @Stephan-   Thanks!   Adding that line didn't help as when I would run as user or admin, it would update the log file in the folder I had designated, but it would not ping anything.   However, since I was able to find where the log file went when running as admin, I am able to get that file now.   Thanks a million!!